# How to assign values to something in a 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, 2d

```
def main():
    create_board()
    print_board()


def create_board():
    for x in range(4):
        board.append(["O"] * 4)

def print_board(): 
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))
```

This is my code to Generate a board for a battleship game. Now what I want to do is to assign a value to each of the zero's. E.g. '1,1' will equal the top left one and '1,2' = the 2nd from top left etc. So when asked:
    Fire('input co ordinates where you want to shoot?')
and if the player inputs e.g.
    1,1
it will know that its firing at the top left

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> print(x)
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]

>>> x[1][1] = 5
>>> print x
[[1, 2], [3, 5]]
```